# How to clearText in edittext and replace with new text in espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am trying trying to replace text "00" by "200" in espresso.Every other editTexts are working fine but this one is giving me error.Please suggest me how to resolve this.I have tried all kind of answers found in stackoverflow but still no luck.I have turned off all the animations and transitions. But still getting error.

This my code snippet:

```
onView(withId(R.id.prepare_bill_cash_received_et_1)).perform(replaceText("200")).perform(closeSoftKeyboard());
```

This is error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'replace text' on view 'with id: com.wenzinslaboratory.lab.foe:id/prepare_bill_cash_received_et_1'.
```

this is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/cash_received"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center|start" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/prepare_bill_cash_received_et_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:maxLength="6" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/prepare_bill_cash_received_et_2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".1"
                    android:maxLength="2"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show the layout xml file

Comment: i have updated the xml file please check out

Comment: Show full stacktrace.